# Objective-c program crashes when adding object to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, crash, nsmutablearray

So, I'm kind of new to Obj-c, and I have a strange crash happening with the following code :

```
- (NSMutableArray*)followNonBlackPixels:(int)startX withY:(int)startY
{
    NSMutableArray* result;
    NSMutableArray* adjacents = [self getAdjacents:startX withY:startY];

    int r = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int tempX;
    int tempY;
    int max = [adjacents count];
    CGPoint tempPoint;
    while(i < max)
    {
        int tempX = (int)[[adjacents objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].x;
        int tempY = (int)[[adjacents objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].y;

        result = [self getAdjacents:tempX withY:tempY];

        for(r = 0; r < [result count]; r++)
        {
            tempPoint = [[result objectAtIndex:r] CGPointValue];
            //[adjacents addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y)]];
        }

        i++;
        max = [adjacents count];
    }

    return adjacents;
}
```

This code runs fine, but as soon as I uncomment the line where I add an object to the "adjacents" NSMutableArray, then the program crashes.

The signature of the getAdjacents method is as follows:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getAdjacents:(int)startX withY:(int)startY;
```

I'm developing a Cordova plugin under Windows so I do not have any debug info to provide... But maybe my mistake would be clear to an experienced obj-c developer ?

Thanks a lot for you help !

Comment: You don't have a crash log? My guess is that in fact `adjacents` is a `NSArray` and not a `NSMutableArray`, but that's pure speculation.

Comment: Are you sure getAdjacents returns a *mutable* array? Despite the signature the returning object may still be just an NSArray.

Comment: Can you post your crash log so it will be easy to find where is the issue?

Comment: Can you try `NSMutableArray* adjacents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [self getAdjacents:startX withY:startY]];` and then check, while initialization?

Comment: I cannot find any crash log, no... Nothign with any relevant info anyway.
I tried your solution @SaurabhYadav, but no luck...
I'm sure getAdjacents return a mutable array, as it start with `NSMutableArray* adjacents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` and return that array after filling it.

Comment: Can you check that [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y)] != nil

Comment: I checked and it's not null

Comment: i Think your method getAdjecent: not returning a mutable array . . . so try this one  NSMutableArray* adjacents = [[self getAdjacents:startX withY:startY] mutableCopy];

Comment: It did not help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code to the following,

```
NSMutableArray *adjacents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self getAdjacents:startX withY:startY] mutableCopy]];
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue... I tried but still, it crashes.

Comment: Is it possible to show me the code for 'getAdjacents', just so I debug everything? Surprising using 'mutableCopy' didn't work. Could you post what the crash message is, it should just be in your console, maybe 'unrecognised selector' or something like that.

Comment: I do not have access to a console as I develop under windows. It's a cordova plugin, compiled with Telerik CLI.

Comment: We can continue this is chat if that's okay, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135918/ios

Comment: @Scalpweb did this solution actually fix the problem? Your comments above imply that it doesn't. If you have fixed your problem then post an answer documenting the fix as otherwise this answer is useless for other users finding it. If this answer did fix the problem then edit your previous comment or add a new one.

Comment: The issue was not entirely fixed by the code above, but it helped. And we spend some time on a chat session and I ended up finding a bug somewhere else too, but in another method.